# apply stroke on textview in android xml not by canvas

Tags: android, textview, stroke

I am unable to find how to achieve stroke on textview from XML , not by canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imitate a stroke with a text shadow:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:shadowColor="#000000"
   android:shadowDx="0.0"
   android:shadowDy="0.0"
   android:shadowRadius="2.0" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Bond turns out the code was there just not properly spaced ^^. Thanks @ spalttne.